# Adding xts-attributes to the results of an XTS filter/query

Tags: r, xts

I have an `XTS` object with multiple variables and I want to add custom attributes to each variable.  The `xts` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/vignettes/xts.pdf) provides some guidance on this (pp 20).  I want each variable within the `XTS` object (or list of objects) to have separate values for these attributes.  I believe `xtsAttributes` can NOT be assigned to `xts` queries.  Is this correct and if so which of the following solutions is best (or  provide an alternate)?

a) break the `XTS` object up into a list of `XTS` objects and assign the attributes individually. (likely the preferred option, but not ideal as I'd like to keep all the variables bound to the same time index)

b) keep an indexed lookup table of the attributes along with the single `XTS` object and retrieve these attributes separately. (messy)

c) extend the `xts` class to handle this (doubtful)

Code reference:

```
a<-xts(matrix(1:4, ncol=2, nrow=2), as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2018-01-01")))
xtsAttributes(a[,1])<-list(myattr="foo")
xtsAttributes(a[,1])
#NULL
xtsAttributes(a)<-list(myattr="foo")
xtsAttributes(a)
#[1] "foo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some opinions/suggestions:

*"I have an XTS object with multiple variables and I want to add custom attributes to each variable."*

An xts object doesn't have "multiple variables" .  An xts object consistents of basically a  matrix of data (of type numeric or character typically), and a vector of times (type date or POSIXct).

*"I want each variable within the XTS object (or list of objects) to have separate values for these attributes. I believe xtsAttributes can NOT be assigned to xts queries"*

This doesn't quite make sense to me, but I would speculate that you might mean you want different attributes for different column names.  iIf that's the case, you could make the names of the list reflect the column names in the xts object.  e.g.

```
xtsAttributes(a)<-list(Open = "a", Close = list(1:10, rep("A", 3)), Volume = "NYSE")
```

Access the attribute values using `xtsAttributes(a)$Open`, etc

xtsAttributes simply are a way of attaching meta data to an xts object which won't disappear if you do things like subset (according to time) the xts object.  Using your example:

```
> str(a)
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-01/2018-01-01 containing:
  Data: int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 1
 $ myattr: chr "foo"
> b <- a["2015"]
> str(b)
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-01/2015-01-01 containing:
  Data: int [1, 1:2] 1 3
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 1
 $ myattr: chr "foo"
```

`b`  still contains the meta data `foo`.

If you want to have a time index on your meta data, then make a separate xts object for this purpose:

```
> xx <-xts(matrix(c("Annoucement1", "Announcement2")), as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2018-01-01")))
> xx
           [,1]           
2015-01-01 "Annoucement1" 
2018-01-01 "Announcement2"
# Return all announcements up to 2016
> xx["/2016"]
           [,1]          
2015-01-01 "Annoucement1"
```

a) and b) can probably be better addressed other ways if they aren't "timeless" metadata that could go in `xtsAttributes`.  Maybe a list of data.frame items (where each list item corresponds to a particular symbol) would work better.

c) sounds a bit like premature optimisation (of code) ... only do that if you're really sure you have a repeated use case for the extended class you have in mind.

Personally, I've never found a need for xtsAttributes.  Consider this use case for financial data as one way to address your problem: Store related data for your financial data on a stock, or financial instrument inside another related object.  For example, the R `quantstrat` library uses `stock` objects (from the `FinancialInstrument` package) that are associated with the time series financial data for the stock in an xts object.   See `quantstrat` demos for more information.  The "map"/"key" between the financial data (the xts object) and the meta data (in the "stock object") in that case is the name of the stock.

For example:

```
library(quantmod)
library(FinancialInstrument)

> getSymbols("AAPL")
> head(AAPL)
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2007-01-03    95.539    95.860   90.679   83.80000   309579900      10.81246
2007-01-04    93.059    95.163   92.804   85.66000   211815100      11.05245
2007-01-05    94.964    95.440   93.447   85.04999   208685400      10.97374
2007-01-08    95.174    95.805   94.421   85.47000   199276700      11.02793
2007-01-09    95.716   102.946   94.277   92.57000   837324600      11.94403
2007-01-10   104.906   108.283  103.467   97.00000   738220000      12.51562

currency("USD")
[1] "USD"
# You could add meta data here:
> stock("AAPL", currency = "USD", tick_size = 0.01, identifiers = list("foo" = 1233, "blah" = "text"))
[1] "AAPL"
# Want to get meta data for the `AAPL` xts object
> getInstrument("AAPL")
primary_id :"AAPL"
currency   :"USD"
multiplier :1
tick_size  :0.01
identifiers:List of 2
 ..$ foo :1233
 ..$ blah:"text"
type       :"stock"
```

Comment: Thanks -- variables in a TS context equate to columns in an XTS object.  I did look at the quantstrat package but opted not to use it given this a general timeseries problem (not exclusively related to finance/trading).  The meta-data is not time bound, and as you suggest is likely best managed in a separate data.frame/tbl with a common set of IDs to the XTS object.  Many thanks for the detailed response.